# Problem on adding Ajax and Js into PHP file for autosuggest script

Tags: php, ajax

I am having trouble to embed an autosuggest script into my existing php file (wordpress). Below is the code and here is the desired result http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/
In addition, the tags system of stackoverflow is great, I am looking something like this one :D

Howvere, instead of the text field I get a select field. It might be something with javascript, I dont know...

**The code:**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>FCBKcomplete Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script src="jquery.fcbkcomplete.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
</head>
<body id="test">
    <h1>FCBKcomplete Demo</h1>
    <div id="text">
    </div>
    <form action="submit.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <select id="select3" name="select3">
            <option value="test1">sleep</option>
            <option value="test3">sport</option>
            <option value="test3">freestyle</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){                
            $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
                json_url: "data.txt",
                addontab: true,                   
                height: 2                    
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="testme"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a `select` tag in your HTML there instead of `input type="text"`. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I confess that I laugh a lot... but seems to be he already fixed it.

Comment: Well if you see the demo at http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/ and the source code at https://github.com/emposha/FCBKcomplete/archives/master you will see that the above code it is correct

Comment: @Mairoula: In any case, you need to provide more information. May I suggest trying Firebug in Firefox, the developer console in Chrome, or something equivalent and reporting what JS errors it reports, if any?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer. Do you think the problem is that I try to embed javascript in a php file ?

Comment: @Mairoula: No, that's not a problem. What's really stopping you right now is the fact that you can't describe the problem (which in turn is because you don't have a clear idea of how what you are trying to do works). Try to offer more and better information (for example any JS errors, as I mentioned above).